# JPA from Maven repository with Ivy

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2, jpa, ivy

I'm converting an existing project using JPA + Hibernate to use Ivy for getting its dependencies. I can get almost everything, but have trouble getting JPA. This is my **ivy.xml** without JPA:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="xxx" module="dataserver"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="commons-logging" name="commons-logging" rev="1.1.1"/>
        <dependency org="com.google.guava" name="guava" rev="r07"/>
        <dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.16"/>
        <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-entitymanager" rev="3.4.0.GA"/>
        <dependency org="c3p0" name="c3p0" rev="0.9.1.2"/>
        <dependency org="mysql" name="mysql-connector-java" rev="5.1.14"/>
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.6.1"/>
        <dependency org="org.apache.openjpa" name="openjpa-persistence" rev="2.1.0"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

I expected to easily find JPA in the Maven repository, but it wasn't so. After a while I found OpenJPA:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="xxx" module="dataserver"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="commons-logging" name="commons-logging" rev="1.1.1"/>
        <dependency org="com.google.guava" name="guava" rev="r07"/>
        <dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.16"/>
        <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-entitymanager" rev="3.4.0.GA"/>
        <dependency org="c3p0" name="c3p0" rev="0.9.1.2"/>
        <dependency org="mysql" name="mysql-connector-java" rev="5.1.14"/>
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.6.1"/>
        <dependency org="org.apache.openjpa" name="openjpa-persistence" rev="2.1.0"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Though it's slow to download, it does appear to contain the interfaces/classes I was missing, such as `EntityManager`. However, it's not the same as the JPA version distributed with Hibernate I had, because I'm now missing the method `EntityManager.createQuery(String, Class)`. But I couldn' t find any newer version of OpenJPA than 2.1.0.

What's the proper JPA source in the Maven repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still have the maven version you could call `mvn dependency:tree` and see the groupid and artifactid that hibernate would define on its dependency (unless hibernate is provided).

Edit:

We have those hibernate dependencies using maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's the ivy.xml equivalent:

```
<dependency org="org.hibernate" name="ejb3-persistence" rev="1.0.2.GA"/>
<dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-annotations" rev="3.4.0.GA"/>
<dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-core" rev="3.3.2.GA"/>
```

Comment: It never was a Maven project. It went from nothing to Ivy, but uses the Maven repositories.

Comment: Please see my edit for the hibernate deps we are using. That should be all you need. The `EntityManager` interface is located in `ejb3-persistence`.

Answer (score 1):

Can I improve on Thomas's answer by suggesting using a configuration mapping. This will exclude the jars marked "optional" in the Hibernate modules (For example, you don't need to download ANT)

The following example lists 3 configurations corresponding to the 3 main scopes in a Maven module.

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
  <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo1"/>
  <configurations defaultconfmapping="compile->default">
    <conf name="compile" description="Compile dependencies"/>
    <conf name="runtume" description="Runtime dependencies" extends="compile"/>
    <conf name="test" description="Test dependencies" extends="runtime"/>        
  </configurations>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="ejb3-persistence" rev="1.0.2.GA"/>
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-annotations" rev="3.4.0.GA"/>
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-core" rev="3.3.2.GA"/>
  </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Note the **defaultconfmapping** attribute. This tells ivy to download the jars from the "default" configuration which in Maven is the "compile" scope.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Hibernate uses the JBoss maven repository, which should be enabled in your system:

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Users

Comment: The Hibernate jars are present in Maven central.

Comment: Sorry but no, it's not. Older versions are there, up to 3.3.2.GA. Newer are in the JBoss Nexus repository: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.0.0.Alpha1/

Answer (score 0):

I found this post very useful to setup ivy to consume maven repositories: http://www.mattgoldspink.co.uk/2010/06/19/re-visiting-spring-ivy-and-maven-copy-and-paste-configs/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://code.google.com/p/ivyroundup/?